# Rails console vs a rake task: returning File.size is not consistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rake-task, rails-console

I'm having a strange issue where when I check the File.size of a particular file in Rails console, it returns the correct size. However when I run the same code in a rake task, it returns 0. Here is the code in question (I've tidied it up a bit to help with readability):

```
def sum_close
  daily_closed_tickets = Fst.sum_retrieve_closed_tickets
  daily_closed_tickets.each do |ticket|
      CSV.open("FILE_NAME_HERE", "w+", {force_quotes: false}) do |csv|
          if (FileCopyReceipt.exists?(path: "#{ticket.attributes['TroubleTicketNumber']}_sum.txt")) 
              csv << ["GENERATE CSV WITH ATTRIBUTES HERE"]
              files = Dir.glob("/var/www/html/harmonize/public/close/CLOSED_#{ticket.attributes['TroubleTicketNumber']}_sum.txt")
              files.each do |f|
                  Rails.logger.info "File size (should return non-0): #{File.size(f)}" #returns 0, but not in Rails Console
                  Rails.logger.info "File size true or false, should be true: #{File.size(f) != 0}" #returns false, should return true
                  Rails.logger.info "Rails Environment: #{Rails.env}" #returns production
                  if(!FileCopyReceipt.exists?(path: f) && (File.size(f) != 0))
                      Rails.logger.info("SUM CLOSE, GOOD => FileUtils.cp_r occurred and FileCopyReceipt object created")            
                  else
                      Rails.logger.info("SUM CLOSE, WARNING: => no data transfer occurred")
                  end
              end
          else
              Rails.logger.info("SUM CLOSE => DID NOT make it into initial if ClosedDate.present? if block")
          end
      end
  end
```

close_tickets.rake

```
task :close_tickets => :environment do
    tickets = FstController.new
    tickets.sum_close
    tickets.dais_close
end
```

It is beyond me why this File.size comes back as 0 when this is run as a rake task. I thought it may be a environment issue, but that does not seem to be the case.

Any insight on the matter is appreciated.

Comment: Can you run the entire method from `rails console` and get correct results, or are you just trying `File.size` with the file in question? The definition of your Rake task might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run the method as in in rails console, it still returns file size of 0. When I run the method line by line (ie typing out each line) in Rails console, it returns the correct results: http://i.imgur.com/beK6g3K.jpg (the top half of that SS is the tail-end of running the method all in one go, the bottom half is the file sizes when running the method line by line). Adding rake task definition to OP.

Comment: I'm at a loss, but it must be something in the code path of that method. I would put a `puts File.size("/var/www/html/harmonize/public/close/CLOSED_123456_sum.txt")` call at the top of your method -- with an existing ticket number -- before anything else runs, and see if that prints the right value or not. If it does, move the line lower and lower in the method until it stops, in order to isolate what causes the problem. If it doesn't, move that line up into the first line in your Rake task definition and see if that works or not.

Comment: Cheers on the debugging tips. It has to do with that |csv| block, if you notice the whole method is more or less wrapped in there, which was causing problems. Will post answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The `CSV.open` block and everything being wrapped in there was causing issues. So I just made CSV generation it's own snippet instead of wrapping everything in there.

```
daily_closed_tickets.each do |ticket|
    CSV.open("generate csv here.txt") do |csv|
        #enter ticket.attributes here for the csv
    end
    #continue on with the rest of the code and File.size() works properly
end
```